# SQUID proxy + iptables

Tags: firewall, iptables, proxy, squid

I'm using **squid3** (on **ubuntu 10.10**) and it manage connection completelly fine.

But how can I secure the traffic by setting the firewall on the **same serve**r?

If I use firewalls like `ufw` or `firestarter`, I'm not able to allow the squid port.

So I've tried to add some rules to iptables.up.rules, e.g.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 3128
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 80
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -o eth1 -p tcp --sport 80
```

Connection works, but I think iptables doesn't.
How to make iptables to **deny all the traffic** and **allow choosed ports** only?

Answer (score 2):

You should set your INPUT policy to DENY, so all traffic that does not explicitly match one of the above rules is rejected.

I would also consider dropping the OUTPUT rules, since these add no extra security.

Comment: Thanks.. something like this? -A INPUT -j REJECT; -A FORWARD -j REJECT

Comment: And the second thing - it tells me, there is some problem with -t parameter in first line (Line 24 seems to have a -t table option). Dont you know where could be an error?

Comment: That does not change the POLICY on those chains.

Comment: Aha, -P INPUT (OUTPUT, FORWARD) DROP